# How do I install gpointing-device?

Tags: software-installation, permissions, touchpad, lock

I would like to install the gpointing-device-settings package which I found on the Launchpad website 
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gpointing-device-settings

I tried:

```
apt-get install gpointing-device-settings
```

but I get the following reply:

```
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
```

I also tried

```
add-apt-repository ppa:gpointing-device-settings
```

and got

```
Error: must run as priviledged user
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction please as I seem to have got my brain into a loop...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as it saying you need to do the procedure as root user. simple add sudo. In Ubuntu to install anything you must be a root user.

I mean

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gpointing-device-settings
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gpointing-device-settings
```

then you will have it installed .

Comment: unfortunatly,[code]sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gpointing-device-settings
Cannot access PPA (https://launchpad.net/api/1.0/~gpointing-device-settings/+archive/ppa) to get PPA information, please check your internet connection.[/code] The internet connection is working as I am posting this through it. Thanks for that suggestion, any other ideas?

Comment: I can download the file from https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/raring/+source/gpointing-device-settings but as a Unix neweb I have no idea how to install it.

Comment: to install a .deb file just type `sudo dpkg -i herefilename.deb`

Comment: After searching the unpacked files, I can not find a .deb file

Comment: Hey you no need to add PPA even , just open your terminal and type as `sudo apt-get install gpointing-device-settings` . That will do the job.

Comment: Jai, you are brilliant. Thank you so much. Unfortunately, the options on mouse and touchpad stayed the same :(

Comment: @SimplySimon did you have `libgpds-dbg` and `gsynaptics `installed.

Comment: I cannot get this working in Debian 8.1, although it should work.

Comment: Let see any libs are missing , try to launch gsynaptics  from terminal , are you getting any errors ?

Comment: Getting the error: `Package gpointing-device-settings is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source`.

Comment: Try to do apt-cache search string name  after adding that PPA. in any case if installation package name modified then you will find it.

Comment: Found a way to install it here: http://askubuntu.com/a/783234/13330

Comment: Glad you found it

Answer (score 0):

There is a rather undocumented command in the Synaptics touch pad driver:

```
synclient TouchpadOff=0/1.
```

Set it to '1' to disable the touch pad.
To make it persistent, add a startup program with this command (in Ubuntu or Debian).
Neat, isn't it?There is a rather undocumented command in the Synaptics touch pad driver:

```
synclient TouchpadOff=0/1.
```

Set it to '1' to disable the touch pad.
To make it persistent, add a startup program with this command (in Ubuntu or Debian).
Neat, isn't it?

credits:firdavis on url :-http://xmodulo.com/how-to-disable-touchpad-on-debian-ubuntu-desktop.html