# Is gpointing-device-settings in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: apt, 16.04

I cannot find it in apt-get. It is in 14.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't install it, it works just the very first time and don't work after reboot [gpointing-device-settings lost on reboot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64334/gpointing-device-settings-lost-on-reboot)

Better use workaround like this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/101867/make-mouse-movements-scroll-when-the-middle-button-is-held-down?noredirect=1&lq=1

Use `xinput` commands, as explain in the response of the link above.

Comment: Can you please summarise the contents of the unix thread? Such that your answer is not only link-only answer.

Answer (score 6):

It is not in the repos for 16.04 but it is available on [launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/amd64/gpointing-device-settings/1.5.1-6ubuntu2)

Install from the .deb with

```
sudo dpkg -i gpointing-device-settings_1.5.1-6ubuntu2_amd64.deb
```

Comment: Technically, it's not "released". That's just the last available build before the package was deleted: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/amd64/gpointing-device-settings

Comment: @muru Fair enough, I changed it.

Comment: Why was it deleted? What's its successor?

Comment: Also, will it work? Perhaps it was deleted because some features don't work.

Comment: Don't know why it go deleted. It should work though, the answer was accepted. @AlikElzin-kilaka

Comment: The answer was how to install it. The person who installed might not have used it. Linux can be very frustrating sometimes, like why isn't there an explanation for the removal? Perhaps there is but I didn't find one.

Comment: You want to remove it? `checkinstall` installs it as a .deb, so `sudo apt-get purge gpointing-device-settings`. @AlikElzin-kilaka

Comment: I meant, Why was the package removed from the repos? There was not explanation to why it was removed.

Comment: That dpkg command didn't work for me until I also manually installed libgpds0 from https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/amd64/libgpds0/1.5.1-6ubuntu2 .

Comment: All versions https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gpointing-device-settings

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is available. You have to enable the "Universe" repository in your package management settings or by uncommenting the lines for the universe repo in your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file.

However, it doesn't seem to work well and it crashes constantly.

[Click here for more info on how to enable the Universe repository.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository)