# Trouble installing dependencies for gpointing-device-settings. Error with gnome-settings-daemon

Tags: xubuntu, gnome-settings-daemon

I've been installing all the required dependencies for gpointing-device-settings which I don't have (figuring out by running ./configure and seeing what causes errors). But I've gotten to an error that I have not been able to get past.

[screenshot of terminal displaying error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2tR0.png)

I've done

1. install gnome-settings-daemon but that doesn't stop the error

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-settings-daemon
```

[and installing the .deb file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2Mad.png)
which results in more dependency issues (which I get even though they are installed)

2. add path of gnome-settings-daemon to PATH and to PKG_CONFIG_PATH
   added the following to .profile

```
export PATH="/usr/lib:$PATH"
export PATH="$HOME/usr/lib:$PATH"
PATH="/usr/lib:$PATH"
PATH="$HOME/usr/lib:$PATH"
```

have extra just in case (I'm a beginner and just wanted to make sure that I wasn't doing it wrong so I put in every combination)

[paths as seen on terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gEuJt.png)

Comment: Does it meet the required version for this install?

Comment: You haven't told us your release, and as George has already said - does your release of Xubuntu meet the requirements (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=gnome-settings-daemon)   Please don't provide pictures of text; we can't copy/paste them into windows (where as with text we can).

Comment: I think it's Xubuntu 18.04 (not sure if that's too vague). Also based on the link you sent me (guiverc), am I supposed to add the specified line to "/etc/apt/sources.list" and install the .deb file they provide? Or just do one of the two? Or do something completely different? I'm a beginner and don't yet understand how it all works. Installing the .deb file doesn't seem to work (but I may be doing it wrong)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are trying to compile the program its source code.

In such case you need to install special development packages (with `-dev`) suffix.

As the result [you will get needed](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/amd64/gnome-settings-daemon-dev/filelist) headers and Pkg-Config file(s) - `.pc`.

In this particular case you need to enable source code repositories in Software & Updates (`software-properties-gtk`) and install `gnome-settings-daemon-dev` package with:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-settings-daemon-dev
```

and then proceed.

---

Also you can try to use binary packages way:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/gpointing-device-settings/libgpds0_1.5.1-6ubuntu2_amd64.deb
sudo apt install ./libgpds0_1.5.1-6ubuntu2_amd64.deb

wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/gpointing-device-settings/gpointing-device-settings_1.5.1-6ubuntu2_amd64.deb
sudo apt install ./gpointing-device-settings_1.5.1-6ubuntu2_amd64.deb
```

---

About your original problem - you can find [this thread about `touchpad-indicator`](https://askubuntu.com/a/1053119/66509) useful.

Comment: that did fix the issue I was having with gnome-settings-daemon, thanks! I tried touchpad-indicator, but it has some defaults that I don't think I can change (like mouse acceleration). So I've removed it. I'm still hoping to install gpointing-.... do you think that would work? Based on the little I read from the post you linked gpointing-... has been discontinued and probably won't work for a Xubuntu 18.04 system. Do you know of another way I could disable the tap to click? (pretty much all I want to do, causes a lot of issues for me)

Comment: I'm not familiar with tap-to-click problem, some posts here mention `synclient`, but I have never used it. On my MATE system I have set it in `mate-mouse-properties` (see [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xU3rG.png)). If you want to proceed with `gpointing-device-settings`, you can try binary packages first (see update above).